# extra code after spin() function is not executed

Tags: c++, vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm working on a c++ project which needs to combine pcl and vtk.
but,  i have a problem when using **spin** function to update scene.
I know that **spin** function calls **spinOnce** in  an infinite loop to update 
scene in pcl visualizser.. 
but I'm working on a project where i need to execute some code after using 
**spin** function . 
this code could be like:

```
void addBoundingBox() 
{ 
  // add vtkBoxWidget2 to the pcl visualizer.
  m_label = new BoundingBoxLabel(m_pclViewer, 
  ia::annotalight::common::AnnnotationKinds::CAR); 
  m_label->addLabel(*m_labelingService); 
  m_pclViewer->spin(); 
  // i need to execute this code to add the vtkBox to a QTreeWidget.
  setAllLabels(m_labelingService); 
  initLabelsList(); 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you already found the problem? Perhaps you could look into adding another thread, or possibly running the code before the infinite loop?

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, i'm trying to use another thread but, i hope that will be another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** - there is no other way

As you've already realized `PCLVisualizer::spin()` is a blocking method. If you want to execute code without destroying the window, you immediately are required to start using `PCLVisualizer::spinOnce()`. If you want to keep the "scene" refreshed and handling input events you'll need to keep it inside a loop of this sort

```
while (!viewer->wasStopped ())
{
  viewer->spinOnce (100);
  // (optional) boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
}
```

Everything you add or modify will need to be done either inside that loop or outside of this thread. Just make sure to avoid modifying the contents of your rendering window while `spinOnce()` is running.